# failsafe ssh with multiple ip's for single station

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I want to be able to issue a command like the following:

```
ssh mark
```

Given that mark is a host configured in the `ssh_config` file like this:

```
host mark
    hostname 192.168.0.10 
    user root
```

This works ok given that I've copied my public key to that station.
What I want is to be able to configure multiple ip addresses in the `hostname` field in case one of marks's interfaces goes offline.
I would like something like:

```
hostname 192.168.0.10,192.168.0.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add single host name and let your domain name server returns multiple IP addresses (hint check CNAME).